# How do I query amount of child records in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a many to many relationship between `Items` and `Categories`.

I am trying to pull out the number of items belonging to each category in next format: `[category.id, <number of items>]`

Here is what I have so far:

```
Category.joins(:items).select('id, count(id) as quantity')
```

But it doesn't work. Could anyone help me and point to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are multiple problems:**

- `id, count(id) as quantity` is ambiguous, `categories.id, count(items.id) as quantity` is better
- `joins` produces `INNER JOIN`, but you probably want to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`
- `GROUP BY` is not specified

**For Ruby on Rails >= 5 you use:**

```
categories = Category.select('categories.id, count(items.id) as quantity').
                      left_outer_joins(:items).
                      group(:id)

category = categories.first

category.id #=> 12
category.quantity #=> 34
```

**For Ruby on Rails < 5 you replace `left_outer_joins(:items)` with:**

```
joins('left outer join items on items.category_id = categories.id')
```

**A Note About `to_sql`**

It may be helpful to know you can call `to_sql` on `Relation` to view the SQL which is going to be run. If you call it against your code you will see:

```
select id,
       count(id) as quantity
from `categories`
inner join `items` ON `items`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
```

Which does not make much sense. And here is what we get after applying the changes:

```
select categories.id,
       count(items.id) as quantity
from `categories`
left outer join `items` ON `items`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id`
group by `categories`.`id`
```

Comment: Thanks so much for such an in depth answer! You explained this all perfectly. I'm still a beginner with these activerecord methods and SQL in general, but I feel like I have a pretty solid grasp now.